# What to do when DefinitelyTyped type definitions are for a newer version than what I want?

Tags: typescript, definitelytyped

I'm trying to use [async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async)'s [filter](https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/v1.5.2/README.md#filterarr-iterator-callback) function, which from the doc for v1.5.2 (the one you get by default if you `npm i async`), takes a single (boolean) value for the callback in the iterator:

> iterator(item, callback) - A truth test to apply to each item in arr. The iterator is passed a callback(truthValue), which must be called with a boolean argument once it has completed.

I have checked [the code](https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/v1.5.2/lib/async.js#L407-L412) and it is true of this version.

The problem is that the release candidate being worked on for async v2 seems to change this to take the usual (error, value) callback. This latter definition is what's being used by the type definitions for async in DefinitelyTyped:

```
interface AsyncBooleanIterator<T> { (item: T, callback: (err: string, truthValue: boolean) => void): void; }
// ...
filter<T>(arr: T[], iterator: AsyncBooleanIterator<T>, callback?: AsyncResultArrayCallback<T>): any;
```

What happens now? I can't issue a PR because the current type definitions are the future of async. But I get an error using async how I'm suppose to for v1.5.2. Are there different versions I can access for DefinitelyTyped type defs?

I'm starting out with Typescript and have heard of something called merging. Apparently, it's possible to extend the definition of `AsyncBooleanIterator` to be one which can also take a callback with a single boolean argument… but I'm not sure how to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of the previous versions - view history and pick appropriate commit.
If you want manually allow both callback signatures you can do something like this:

```
interface AsyncBooleanIterator<T> {
    (item: T, callback: ((truthValue: boolean) => void) | ((err:string,truthValue:boolean) => void)): void;
}
```

Comment: Hi Aleksey! So you're saying to pick the commit in all of DefinitelyTyped's history when async.d.ts happens to have the v1.5.2 definition for filter and download it manually in my project? Is this the way people work with DefinitelyTyped? (I've switched to async@2.0.0-rc.6 - easier). Re the AsyncBooleanIterator, I know how that type can be defined to accommodate the old version. But how do I make it take effect? If I just drop that in my file it doesn't work. How can I somehow extend/merge that type definition which is in typings/globals/async/index.d.ts from my ts files?

Comment: In `typings.json` you can specify required commit id. For example: `"ng-file-upload": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/ng-file-upload/ng-file-upload.d.ts#41f8573534b0fff88707d0a4cb870456b50cd43b"`

Comment: Thanks I didn't know that :) Do you know how AsyncBooleanIterator can be extended from outside the DefinitelyTyped file? (for future ref)

Comment: Not sure if this can be done externally because this d.ts file is a module. You can manually editing definitions, but it is kinda nasty. I think using appropriate version is a way to go.